# How to push array keys and values in a session variable in php?

Tags: php, arrays, session

Here is an example (please don't consider the below example, it is not a part of my program)

```
array( 'agur' => 100,
       'agur' => 300,
       'babu' => 200 );
```

The above array values i want to insert into a SESSION variable one by one at a time.

Problem is not the above example array i want to insert. The actual script is like Each and every time when i click a link the values from the query string i want to insert into a SESSION Array.

I've tried the below code this didn't help me!

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION['allmarks'] ) )
{
    $_SESSION['allmarks'] = array();
}
$name = $_GET['name']; //eg. agur
$mark = $_GET['mark']; //eg. 100

$_SESSION['allmarks'] ["$name"] = $mark;
```

The output im getting is only the last value inserted

```
'agur' => 300
```

I've tried `array_push` too, but it didn't help for me!.

I want the result like below when i var_dumb the `SESSION['allmarks']`

```
'agur' => 100
'agur' => 300
'babu' => 200
```

Comment: What happens when you try that?  It's not enough to say "It doesn't work."  We can't tell what the problem is unless you tell us exactly what happens.

Comment: Please `var_dump()` your `$_SESSION` right before and after the declaration of the array key. What does it return? Is the result what you expect it to be or is it any different?

Comment: doesnt make sense to have two identical keys. make it a map from strings in lists of numbers if you want this use case

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `foreach` and loop the array,

```
  $arr  = array( 'agur' => 100,  'agur' => 300,   'babu' => 200 ); 
  if( !isset( $_SESSION['allmarks'] ) )
  {
    $_SESSION['allmarks'] = array();
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
     $_SESSION['allmarks'][$k] = $v; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach() for walking through array

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop if you want to just set a session key to this array.

Also, don't forget `session_start()` (common mistake).

```
$array = array( 'agur' => 100,
       'agur' => 300,
       'babu' => 200 ); 

session_start();
$_SESSION['allmarks'] = $array;
```

Comment: Did you print out `$array` to notices that you can't have duplicated keys on the firsts level?